A vectorial estimate I can't understand.
Let $w\in (0, \kappa], p < 1, p\neq 0, \alpha \in (0, 1), \beta(1-p) -Kp>0, \sigma\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, $invertible, and $ \mu, \eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
I want to estimate $|\mathbf u|$, where
$\mathbf u = wV_{ww}(w, z)(\sigma\sigma^t)^{-1}\mu-z\sigma_Z V_{wz}(w, z)(\sigma\sigma^t)^{-1}(\sigma\eta)+z\sigma_Z(\sigma\sigma^t)^{-1}(\sigma\eta)$
And I know $V_{ww}(w, z) = \frac{1-p}{\beta(1-p)-Kp}w^{-\frac{1}{1-p}-1} + z(1-\alpha)\kappa^{1-\alpha}w^{\alpha -2}$ and $V_{wz}(w, z) = 1-\kappa^{1-\alpha}w^{\alpha-1} $.
Is the following estimate correct?
$|\mathbf u| \le |(\sigma\sigma^t)^{-1}\mu|\bigg(\frac{\kappa}{2}\bigg)^{-\frac{1}{1-p}}\frac{1}{\beta - \frac{Kp}{1-p}}+\bigg(|(\sigma\sigma^t)^{-1}\mu|(1-\alpha)2^{1-\alpha}+2|\sigma_Z\eta^t\sigma^{-1}|\bigg)z$ for all $z>0, w\in [\kappa/2, \kappa]$? And what about $z>0$ and $w \in (0, \kappa/2)$? I can't go on.
